# How to establish a complex sorting scheme of references in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, sorting

The journal in which I intend to publish has some weird sorting requirements for the reference list. The basic sorting is alphabetical but then (quoting from [here](http://www.wiley.com/bw/submit.asp?ref=1462-2912)):

1. "Papers with two authors should follow those of the first-named author, arranged in alphabetical order according to the name of the second author."
2. "Articles with more than two authors should follow those of the first named author in chronological order"
3. "with multiple references from the same first author in a given year, please list the references in cited order."

Number 1 is of course automatically achieved using `sorting = nyt` but how do I include requirements 2 and 3?
I'm guessing the solution should involve `\DeclareSortingScheme{}` but I haven't got a clue how to code this.

Comment: The publishers are clearly sadists. My advice would be to just ignore that nonsense ... if the publishers care so much, they can have professional typesetters implement their weird reference fetishes. That should not be your responsibility as an author. Otherwise, they have made a `.bst` file available here: http://www.biometrics.tibs.org/biom.bst.txt. Not sure on the mechanics of how that could be included in biblatex specifically.

Comment: I should add, the above file is linked for another journal from the same publishers: http://www.biometrics.tibs.org/latexdocumentclass.htm.

Comment: Journal publishers are known to be sadistic, which would've been accepted if they wouldn't be making such profits on the backs of scientists...  


The journal doesn't provide any LaTeX template (did I mention already they profit from our work without doing much ...).  


I haven't looked into the .bst file since: 1. I'm using biblatex and not bibtex and 2. I'm almost done with my bbx style anyway.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It isn't really clear how these rules should be combined. Based on [reference lists recently published in this journal](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1462-2920.2012.02783.x/references) it appears that any two-author paper should precede a three-or-more-author work having the same first author, regardless of chronology. A similar precedent holds for one-author and two-author works. You can achieve all this by copying the first author and some "large" value into the `sortname` field for every entry with more than two authors.

For one- or two-author entries `sortname` can be left missing by adding the whole `author` list to the same sorting element, as done in the new sorting scheme `emi` below. Further requirements related to citation sorting and name list truncation can easily be achieved with some global option settings. The document also demonstrates a few of these.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,sortcites,sorting=noneyear,
            maxcitenames=1,minbibnames=6,maxbibnames=7]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=author,match=\regexp{\s+and\s.+\s+and\s},final]
      \step[fieldset=sortname,origfieldval]
      \step[fieldsource=sortname,match=\regexp{\s+and\s.+},replace={\ and\ Zzz}]
    }
  }
}

\DeclareSortingScheme{noneyear}{
  \sort{\citeorder}
  \sort{\field{year}}
}

\DeclareSortingScheme{emi}{
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
  }
  \sort{\field{year}}
  \sort{\citeorder}
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ref1,
  author = {First, Joe and Second, Jane and Third, Bob},
  title = {Article title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  date = {2001-01}}
@article{ref2,
  author = {First, Joe and Second, Jane and Third, Bob},
  title = {Article title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  date = {2000-01}}
@book{ref3,
  author = {First, Joe and Third, Bob},
  title = {Book title},
  year = {2002}}
@book{ref4,
  author = {Doe, Joe and Smith, Sam},
  title = {Book title},
  date = {2001}}
@book{ref5,
  author = {Doe, Joe and Brown, Bob},
  title = {Book title},
  date = {2002}}
@book{ref6,
  author = {First, Joe},
  title = {Book title},
  date = {2003}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Filler \parencite{ref1,ref2,ref3,ref4,ref5,ref6}.
Filler \parencite{knuth:ct:c,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:a}.
\printbibliography[sorting=emi]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Audrey for the thorough reply! Your code works great. The only reason I was slow to reply is that I had trouble getting your method to work with my real document. Then I realized that the reason is that I had another `\DeclareSourcemap{` command called from another file using `\input` a few lines later and it ran over yours. Is there a way to have two `\DeclareSourcemap{` commands in one preamble? I tried naming them with `\DeclareSourcemap{name}{` but that gave an error.

Comment: @RoeyAngel There actually is no need for multiple source map declarations. In `\maps` you can use multiple `\map` statements. They are executed in order of appearance. I can clarify with an edit, but I probably need an idea of what mapping other rules you need.

Comment: Thanks, I know how to use multiple `\map` statements in one `\DeclareSourcemap` call the only thing is that my other `\map` call is a file containing many reg exp patterns for turning journal names into abbreviations. The only trouble is that now the code looks a bit ugly. I mind about that because I want others to use the style I'm writing. On the other hand if I can 'shove' everything into the .bbx file that should be ok.

Comment: @RoeyAngel Yeah, I thought a little more and figured you might want an "author-level" source map separate from the user one in the preamble. I asked Philip about it at github. You can follow the issue [here](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/57).

Comment: Brilliant! I think adding an option of a localized `\DeclareStyleSourcemap` would enhance a lot the flexibility of biblatex and will allow me and others to provide more 'intact' biblatex styles, which will require little to no further tweaking on the part of the users.

Comment: I'm really sorry I have to pull the accept, but I've been having trouble with this sorting method.
Everything sort of works at first but if I make a change in the bib database then the sorting gets completely messed up and I am unable to restore it. Could this be that journal name might affect it? 
I am very puzzled about the whole thing...

Comment: @RoeyAngel I can't tell without an example demonstrating the problem. Any changes to your `bib` file would of course need another biber run.

Comment: First I thought the problem was something related to Lyx and it's caching but I was able to reproduce it with LaTeX. I'm working on a minimal example, could I send you by email?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6499/discussion-between-roey-angel-and-audrey)

Comment: Try the biber 1.4 and biblatex 2.4 betas from SF. `\DeclareStyleSourcemap` is now implemented and is applied after user maps but before driver default maps. It's documented in the biblatex PDF manual.

Comment: Could you provide a working example with the newest version of Biber and Biblatex ? This one does not work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think much of this can be achieved without a sourcemapping by using the new-ish `(min|max)sortnames` (https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/755).

With

```
minsortnames=1, maxsortnames=2,
```

you essentially tell `biblatex` to consider at most the first two names for sorting. More precisely,

1. works by `<name_1>` are sorted under `<name_1>`,
2. works by `<name_1> and <name_2>` are sorted after works by only `<name_1>` in the order induced by `<name_2>`,
3. works by more than two authors are sorted under `<name_1> et al.`, which sorts after `<name_1>` and `<name_1> and <name_2>`.

For backwards compatibility reasons setting `(min|max)bibnames` will also set `(min|max)sortnames`, so `(min|max)sortnames` must be set after `(min|max)bibnames`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear,
            sorting=emi, sortcites=true,
            minbibnames=6, maxbibnames=7,
            maxcitenames=1, maxcitenames=2,
            minsortnames=1, maxsortnames=2,
]{biblatex}


\DeclareSortingTemplate{emi}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
  }
  \sort{\citeorder}
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{volume}
    \literal{0}
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ref1,
  author  = {First, Joe and Second, Jane and Third, Bob},
  title   = {Article title},
  journal = {Journal},
  date    = {2001-01},
}
@article{ref2,
  author  = {First, Joe and Second, Jane and Third, Bob},
  title   = {Article title},
  journal = {Journal},
  date    = {2000-01},
}
@book{ref3,
  author = {First, Joe and Third, Bob},
  title  = {Book title},
  year   = {2002},
}
@book{ref4,
  author = {Doe, Joe and Smith, Sam},
  title  = {Book title},
  date   = {2001},
}
@book{ref5,
  author = {Doe, Joe and Brown, Bob},
  title  = {Book title},
  date   = {2002},
}
@book{ref6,
  author = {First, Joe},
  title  = {Book title},
  date   = {2003},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Filler \autocite{ref1,ref2,ref3,ref4,ref5,ref6}.
Filler \autocite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:c}.
Filler \autocite{knuth:ct:b}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sorted output.]