# Correct sort of bibliography

Tags: biblatex, sorting

- Sorted by first author's last name.
- Works only from one author before works with other authors.
- If there is more than one work, then it needs to be like this: 2007a, 2007b,...

Sort should be like this:
Author A:
* Book1 2007
* Book2 2008
* Book 3 2006 other authors

Author B:
...

The minimal working example I have sorts it first by year, then by author last name and sorts the works with other authors after.

If I have multiple works from one author in one year it is correct in the text (shows 2007a etc)
but not in the bibliography, shows:

> Holson, Laura M. Gnome Core Apps. Oct. 28, 2013. URL :link.
>   — KDE Core Apps. Oct. 28, 2013. URL : link.

The publisher is not shown when citing online articles.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel} %bib Last language is main
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes} %bib
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp,sortcites,sorting=ynt,citetracker=true,bibstyle=verbose,backend=biber,maxnames=1,minnames=1,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\AtEveryCitekey{\ifciteseen{}{\defcounter{maxnames}{99}}} %only show all authors
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first} % std is last-first/first-last
%at the first occurrence
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addslash} %replaces and/und with "`/"'
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addslash} %replaces and/und with "`/"'
\bibliography{projectthesis_lit.bib}

\linespread{1.3}
\sloppy%silbentrennung
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

projectthesis_lit.bib:

```
@ONLINE{gnomeApps,
  title = {Gnome Core Apps},
  author = {William Jon McCann},
  year =     {2013},
  month =    {10},
  day = {28},
  url = {https://wiki.gnome.org/action/login/Design/Apps}
}

@ONLINE{gnomeApps2,
  title = {Gnome Core Apps},
  author = {William Jon NcCann},
  year =     {2013},
  month =    {10},
  day = {28},
  url = {https://wiki.gnome.org/action/login/Design/Apps}
}
@ONLINE{gnomeAp23ps2,
  title = {Gnome Core Apps},
  author = {William Jon CcCann},
  year =     {2013},
  month =    {10},
  day = {28},
  url = {https://wiki.gnome.org/action/login/Design/Apps}
}

@ONLINE{gnom213eApps23,
  title = {Gnome Core Apps},
  author = {Laura M. Holson},
  year =     {2013},
  month =    {10},
  day = {28},
  url = {https://wiki.gnome.org/action/login/Design/Apps}
}

@ONLINE{gnom213eApps234,
  title = {KDE Core Apps},
  author = {Laura M. Holson},
  year =     {2013},
  month =    {10},
  day = {28},
  url = {https://wiki.gnome.org/action/login/Design/Apps}
}

@ONLINE{gnom213eApps2,
  title = {Gnome Core Apps},
  author = {Laura M. Holson and Miguel Helft},
  publisher =    {MAMA},
  year =     {2013},
  month =    {10},
  day = {28},
  url = {https://wiki.gnome.org/action/login/Design/Apps}
}

@ONLINE{gnomeAp23423ps2,
  title = {Gnome Core Apps},
  author = {William Jon HeaCcCann},
  publisher =    {Above the Crowd},
  year =     {2013},
  month =    {10},
  day = {28},
  url = {https://wiki.gnome.org/action/login/Design/Apps}
}

@ONLINE{sauce2,
  title = {Gnome Core Apps},
  author = {Bill Gurley},
  publisher =    {Above the Crowd},
  year =     {2013},
  month =    {3},
  day = {24},
  url = {https://wiki.gnome.org/action/login/Design/Apps}
}
```

Comment: Please show the `.bib` entry for the example you have above. Also you should probably not use `bibstyle=verbose,`. if you have `style=authoryear-icomp`.

Comment: Added `.bib`. Why shouldn't I use `bibstyle=verbose`?

Comment: `@online` entries do not have their `publisher` printed, a replacement would be `organization`, that field gets printed for `@online` entries - though I do not see any relevance for that in your example.

Comment: You use the author/year style `authoryear-icomp`, so the bibliography should also be in a author/year style (you for example want to see extra year labels etc.), but `bibtsyle=verbose` loads the `verbose` style for the bibliography, which is essentially an author/title style, so the extra year does not get printed.

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific about your second requirement. I do not get #1 either: Do you want sorting by name-year-title, year-name-title or what?

Comment: #2 see `gnom213eApps23` & `gnom213eApps234`. The `organization` tag worked, thanks. I want it to be sorted: Author, Year, Title. But if there are more authors than the main one, this book should be at the end of this author section. edited post to show sorting

Comment: You've specified the sorting as `ynt` which says you want it sorted by year first, then name, then title. So the first style (`authoryear-icomp`) specifies author-year-title sorting. Then you override that. Then you load a different style (`verbose`).

Comment: I'm sorry, but are these two entries not identical - save for the entry key of course.

Comment: You need sorting `sorting=nyt`, and also need to remove `bibstyle=verbose`.

Comment: @moewe sorry I meant 'gnom213eApps2' and 'gnom213eApps23'

Comment: @cfr I deleted `bibstyle=verbose` and `sorting=ynt` and now it seems to work, thanks :) It even shows 2013a and 2013b

Comment: If I use `sorting=nyt`, I get the "Holson, Laura M." entries *before* "Laura M. Holson and James Helft", which is - I gather - what you want.

Comment: @moewe It isn't necessary to specify `sorting=nyt` as `authoryear` styles already do this automatically. (It won't do any harm to do this - it is just unnecessary.)

Comment: @Rufus_12 Glad that helped. Is this solved, then?

Comment: @cfr authoryear only sorts it by year. that means if the day or month is lower it sorts it as 2013b instead of 2013a, but I need it completely chronological. @ moewe yes this is what I want.

Comment: If you really need completely chronological sorting, you need to define a custom sorting scheme.

Comment: @Rufus_12 I don't think there is an option to sort according to date in that sense - not in standard `biblatex`. You'd either need to load a specialist style (if there is one) or define a custom sort order. Sorting by date isn't a usual requirement of any bibliography style I'm familiar with. Are you sure you really need this?

Comment: Please see [biblatex sorting by date](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46868/35864) and [Sort bibliography with same author and same year (biblatex)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/128387/35864) on how to sort fully chronologically.