# Change alphabet for sorting in biblatex for same year

Tags: biblatex, sorting, alphabet

I take MWE from here [Sort bibliography with same author and same year (biblatex)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128387/sort-bibliography-with-same-author-and-same-year-biblatex)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{lennon1972a,
AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
TITLE = "My music",
YEAR = "1972"}
@BOOK{lennon1972b,
AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
TITLE = "More of my music",
YEAR = "1972"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\cites{lennon1972a}{lennon1972b}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to change 'a'...'b' to another alphabet for a given language alphabet? Let Say to Roman numbering

**EDITED:**

According to answer below I changed code as folllow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{fontspec}
 \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\setmainfont{Dejavu Serif}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{lennon1972a,
AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
TITLE = "My music",
YEAR = "1972"}
@BOOK{lennon1972b,
AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
TITLE = "More of my music",
YEAR = "1972"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat{extrayear}{% = the 'a' in 'Jones 1995a'
  \iffieldnums{labelyear}
 {\Asbuk{#1}}
{\mkbibparens{\Asbuk{#1}}}}
\usepackage{enumitem}
% Some other packages, not needed for MWE
 \AddEnumerateCounter{\Asbuk}{\@Asbuk}{Ы}
 \AddEnumerateCounter{\asbuk}{\@asbuk}{ы}
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{(\Asbuk{enumi})}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\Asbuk{enumi})}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Item A
\item Item B
\end{enumerate}
\cites{lennon1972a}{lennon1972b}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

As you can see Russian letters are outputed for enumitems, but there is an error for biblatex part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `extrayear` field is just a number that you can format as you want.

The default definition (`biblatex.def`) is

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{extrayear}{% = the 'a' in 'Jones 1995a'
  \iffieldnums{labelyear}
    {\mknumalph{#1}}
    {\mkbibparens{\mknumalph{#1}}}}
```

For Roman numerals you can make that read

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{extrayear}{% = the 'a' in 'Jones 1995a'
  \iffieldnums{labelyear}
    {\Rn{#1}}
    {\mkbibparens{\Rn{#1}}}}
```

or `\RN` for uppercase Roman numerals instead of `\Rn`.

For Russian labels as printed by `\asbuk` we need `\russian@alph`

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareFieldFormat{extrayear}{% = the 'a' in 'Jones 1995a'
  \iffieldnums{labelyear}
    {\russian@alph{#1}}
    {\mkbibparens{\russian@alph{#1}}}}
\makeatother
```

(note the `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother` pair).

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{lennon1972a,
AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
TITLE = "My music",
YEAR = "1972"}
@BOOK{lennon1972b,
AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
TITLE = "More of my music",
YEAR = "1972"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\DeclareFieldFormat{extrayear}{% = the 'a' in 'Jones 1995a'
  \iffieldnums{labelyear}
    {\Rn{#1}}
    {\mkbibparens{\Rn{#1}}}}

\begin{document}
\cites{lennon1972a}{lennon1972b}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: so just \Roman does not work right? see udated question

Comment: @LevanShoshiashvili As far as I can see, `\Roman` takes a counter (name) as argument, but we need a macro that can directly take a number. That is why I used `\RN`.

Comment: @LevanShoshiashvili One just needs to identify the function that actually creates the output from the numbers, in this case it is `\russian@alph` (or `\russian@Alph`). Try `\makeatletter
\DeclareFieldFormat{extrayear}{% = the 'a' in 'Jones 1995a'
  \iffieldnums{labelyear}
    {\russian@alph{#1}}
    {\mkbibparens{\russian@alph{#1}}}}
\makeatother`

Comment: Thank you very much...That works...How to define something like '\romannumeral' is different question....Can you give direction for this?

Comment: @LevanShoshiashvili I have added the comment to the answer. Those commands are pretty much straightforward, you might be able to find something on this site. (If not, feel free to ask a new question.) Or just have a look at the definition in russian.ldf.