# Sorting issue with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, sorting

For several years, thanks to this forum, I succeeded for my thesis to achieve a bibliographic style adapted to my needs. However, I just realized now that it is well developed, a sorting issue.

I would like to be sorted by my label and not by name. I would like to have first the author alone, then two authors and finally "authors et al." in ascending order

I found some answers here: [How to establish a complex sorting scheme of references in biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83738/how-to-establish-a-complex-sorting-scheme-of-references-in-biblatex)
However, this seems to create more problems than it solves.

Here is my problem in pictures which will be easier to understand
Here is what I have:  [image]
This is what i would like: [image]

Thanks,
PS: sorry for my big MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}


\usepackage[%
backend=biber,
style=authoryear,
autolang=langname,
uniquename=false, %%enleve le système pour désambiguiser les auteurs
uniquelist=false, %enleve le système pour désambiguiser les auteurs
giveninits,
mergedate=false,
sorting=nyt,
maxcitenames=2,
maxbibnames=999,
mincrossrefs=1, %permet de citer l'entrée mère dès la première mention
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@InProceedings{agusta-boularot2017,
    author    = {Agusta-Boularot, Sandrine},
    title     = {Title},
    booktitle = {booktitle},
    year      = {2017},
    crossref  = {agusta-boularot.etal2017},
}

@InProceedings{agusta-boularot2016,
    author    = {Sandrine Agusta-Boularot},
    title     = {Title},
        year      = {2016},
    booktitle = {booktitle},
}

@Book{agusta-boularot.lafon2004,
    title     = {title},
    year      = {2004},
    editor    = {Sandrine Agusta-Boularot and Xavier Lafon},
}

@Book{agusta-boularot.martin2006,
    title     = {title},
    year      = {2006},
    editor    = {Sandrine Agusta-Boularot and Marin Martin},
}

@InProceedings{augustat-boularot.etal2019,
    author    = {Sandrine Agusta-Boularot and Chausserie-Laprée, Jean and N\'uria Nin},
    title     = {Title},
booktitle = {booktitle},
    year      = {2019},
    timestamp = {2019-09-11},
}

@Article{agusta-boularot.etal2004,
    author       = {Agusta-Boularot, Sandrine and Christol Martin and Pierre Jack},
    title        = {Title},
    journal      = {Journal},
    year         = {2004},
    volume       = {17},
}

@Article{agusta-boularot.etal2010,
    author       = {Sandrine Agusta-Boularot and Raphaël Golosetti and Delphine Isoardi},
    title        = {Title},
    journal      = {Journal},
    year         = {2010},
    pages        = {109-126},
    volume       = {43},
}

@Book{agusta-boularot.etal2017,
    editor    = {Sandrine Agusta-Boularot and Sandrine Huber and William Van Andringa},
    title     = {Title},
    year      = {2017},
}


@InProceedings{paillet.treziny2004,
    author    = {Paillet, Jean-Louis and Henri Tr\'eziny},
    title     = {Title},
booktitle = {booktitle},
    year      = {2004},
    editor    = {Agusta-Boularot, Sandrine},
    crossref  = {agusta-boularot.etal2004},
    timestamp = {2019-12-09},
}




\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


%%%style
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\DeclareNameAlias{byeditor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\space\textendash\space}                  %tiret après le label
\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{}%                                            rajoute date

\DeclareFieldFormat
[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,unpublished]
{title}{#1}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%                                                                 enlève guillemets articles
    \ifentrytype{article}
    {}
    {\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
    \printfield{issue}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printdate%
    \newunit}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1} %enlève le p. automatique pour le postnote dans les citations

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
    \printlist{location}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printlist{publisher}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \usebibmacro{date}%
    \newunit}

%permet de mettre des virgules à la place des deux points après l'adresse
\newbibmacro*{institution+location+date}{%
    \printlist{location}%
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
    \printlist{institution}%
    \newunit\addcomma
}


%Make all thesis/dissertation titles italic
\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{title}{\mkbibitalic{#1}}% %met les titres des theses en italique ; permet également d'enlever les guillements

%Enlever le tiret lorsqu'il y a une récurrence des auteurs
\makeatletter
\AtEveryBibitem{%
    \global\undef\bbx@lasthash%
    \clearfield{extraalpha}}
\makeatother

% "Et al." en ITALIQUE
\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{% Based on name:andothers from biblatex.def
    \ifboolexpr{
        test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
        and
        test \ifmorenames
    }
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
        {\finalandcomma}
        {}%
        \andothersdelim\bibstring[\emph]{andothers}}
    {}}

%%% Histoire des noms    et al...
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
    \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{##1}%
    \defcounter{maxnames}{\blx@maxcitenames}%
    \printtext[bold]{\usebibmacro{cite}\addspace:\space}%
    \defcounter{maxnames}{\blx@maxbibnames}
    \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{\textnohyphenation{##1}}}}
\makeatother

%minuscule citation
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{#1}}

%Enlève parenthèse colloque
\renewbibmacro*{event+venue+date}{
    \iffieldundef{eventtitle}
    {}
    {%
        \bibstring{presentedat}%
        \printfield{eventtitle}%
    }%
    \ifboolexpr{
        test {\iffieldundef{venue}}
        and
        test {\iffieldundef{eventyear}}
    }
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addspace}%
        \printtext{%
            \printfield{venue}%
            \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
            \printeventdate}}%
    \newunit
}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{%
    byeditor = \iffieldequalstr{keywords}{source}%
    {Établit\space par}%
    {dir\adddotspace\smartof},
    in = {\textit{in}},%                                    %et en italique
    editor           = {dir\adddotspace},%
    editors          = {dir\adddotspace},%
    opcit = \iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{article}{art\adddotspace cit\adddot}{\emph{op\adddotspace cit}\adddot},%
    idem = {\emph{idem}},%
    byeditor = {dir\adddot},% Remplace sous la direction de pour les improceedings etc.
    ibidem = {\emph{ibid\adddot}},%
    mathesis = {Mém. de master\addcomma}, %permet de modifier en français le titre et de rajouter un point un espace et une virigule
    phdthesis = {Thèse de doct\adddot\space\addcomma} %permet de modifier en français le titre et de rajouter un point un espace et une virigule
    %pagetotal = {p\adddot},%
    %pages            = {pp\adddot},%
}



%%modifie les pages des articles ... par pp. au lieu de p.
%\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,inproceedings,incollection]{pages}{pp\adddotspace #1}%

%enlève la virugule avant dir.
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{bbx:editor}[1]{%
    \ifboolexpr{
        test \ifuseeditor
        and
        not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
    }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
        {\bibnamedash}
        {\printnames{editor}%
            %   \setunit{\addcomma\space}% DELETED
            \setunit{\addspace}% ADDED
            \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
        %     \usebibmacro{#1}% DELETED
        \printtext{\usebibmacro{#1}}% ADDED
        \clearname{editor}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}
\makeatother

% put (dir.) at the end (byeditor)  pour tout ce qui est in : auteur dir.
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
    \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {%%%\usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}       %%%% suppress
        \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
        \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
        \setunit{\addspace}%
        % \addspace                                  %%%% suppress
        %     \usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}          %%%%
        \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}             %%%%
        \clearname{editor}%            %%%%%%%%%
        \newunit}%
    \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
    \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}

%met entre parenthèse la collection et le numéro dans la même parenthèse
\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
    \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
            \printtext{}%
            \printfield{series}%
            \setunit*{\space}%
            \printfield{number}%
            \printtext{}}%
}} %%% il y a un point en enleveant \nopunct.

%Rajoute une virgule après le titre du journal et avant le numéro du volume
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
    \usebibmacro{journal}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
        \printfield{series}%
        \setunit{\addspace}}%
    \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
    \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
    \usebibmacro{issue}%
    \newunit}

%Permet d'enlever le tiret après in si pas d'auteur.
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
    \ifentrytype{article}
    {}
    {\printtext{\bibstring{in}}%
        \printunit{\intitlepunct}}}

%permet de mettre les initiales entre parenthèses et surtout les particules nobilaires
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{\addspace}


\renewbibmacro*{name:family-given}[4]{%
    \ifuseprefix
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
        \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}%
        \ifdefvoid{#3}{}{%
            \ifcapital
            {\mkbibnameprefix{\MakeCapital{#3}}\isdot}
            {\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
            \ifprefchar{}{\bibnamedelimc}}%
        \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot
        \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamesuffix{#4}\isdot}%
        \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\revsdnamepunct\bibnamedelimd\mkbibparens{\mkbibnamegiven{#2}}\isdot}}% added \mkbibparens
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1}%
        \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}%
        \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot
        \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamesuffix{#4}\isdot}%
        %   \ifdefvoid{#2#3}{}{\revsdnamepunct}%
        \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd\bibopenparen\mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot}% added \bibopenparen
        \ifdefvoid{#3}{}{\bibnamedelimd\ifdefvoid{#2}{\bibopenparen}{}\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}% added \ifdefvoid{#2}{\bibopenparen}{}
        \ifboolexpe{%
            test {\ifdefvoid{#2}}
            and
            test {\ifdefvoid{#3}}}
        {}
        {\bibcloseparen}}}% this line is new

%permet de mettre en minustile les styles de citation
\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}


%rajoute origdate
\renewbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{%
    \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
            \iffieldundef{origyear}{}{[\printfield{origyear}]\addspace}%   <--- added
            \printfield{labelyear}%
            \printfield{extrayear}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
    \iffieldundef{year}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
            \iffieldundef{origyear}{}{\printfield{origyear}]\addspace}%  <--- added
            \printdateextra}}}

%%%%Permet de trier la biblio en suivant l'ordre du label et non pas des noms
%\DeclareSourcemap{
%   \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
%       \map[overwrite]{
%           \step[fieldsource=author,match=\regexp{\s+and\s.+\s+and\s},final]
%           \step[fieldset=sortname,origfieldval]
%           \step[fieldsource=sortname,match=\regexp{\s+and\s.+},replace={\ and\ Zzz}]
%       }
%   }
%}
%
%\DeclareSortingScheme{emi}{
%   \sort{
%       \field{sortname}
%       \field{author}
%   }
%   \sort{\field{year}}
%   \sort{\citeorder}
%}

\begin{document}

\cite{agusta-boularot2017,agusta-boularot2016,agusta-boularot.lafon2004,augustat-boularot.etal2019,agusta-boularot.etal2004,agusta-boularot.etal2010,agusta-boularot.etal2017,paillet.treziny2004,agusta-boularot.martin2006}



\printbibliography[sorting=emi]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is definitely not supported 'officially' in the sense that while Biber has the data available to sort your entries like this there is no interface to specify that. I would have suggested something pretty much along the line of Audrey's answer to the linked question (I think we have a few other related question, but they are had to find ... I will have a look later), but those solutions can be a bit flimsy and usually have edge cases they can't deal with properly.

Comment: The best combination of search keywords I could think of is https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=declaresourcemap+sortname, but there are 50 something hits. Not sure if there is something useful in that list.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to look again on the forum if I find something close to it.
It is surprising that this sorting is not more easily accessible because it is often used in France.
Indeed, if you have time to take a look it would be wonderful because these lines of code are completly arcane for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it should be enough to set `maxsortnames=2,` (i.e. to the same value as `maxcitenames`). Note that `maxsortnames` must be set after `maxbibnames` (because `maxbibnames` sets `maxsortnames` for backwards compatibility, see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/755). `maxsortnames` needs at least `biblatex` v3.12 (2018-10-30).

`maxsortnames=2,` is enough because it forces `biblatex` to sort by exactly the same names that appear in the citation label. "`<Name>` et al." is always sorted after `<Name>` (unless `nosortothers` is set to `true`, see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/861). And `<Name> <Name 2>` also always sorts after `<Name>` but before `<Name> et al.`.

So you want to load `biblatex` with the following name options

```
  maxbibnames=999,
  maxcitenames=2,
  maxsortnames=2,
  uniquename=false,
  uniquelist=false,
  giveninits,
```

I modernised your MWE slightly and removed redundant code. I also based it onto `ext-authoryear` from my [`biblatex-ext` bunde](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext) (instead of `authoryear`), since that makes a few things much easier (for example the bold repetition of the citation label can be produced with the option `introcite=true,`). (Needless to say I probably missed a few things and this does not completely reproduce the exact style you have at the moment. In case you want to pursue this further, just ask a new question about the things I missed. Ideally one issue per question.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[%
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear,
  maxbibnames=999,
  maxcitenames=2,
  maxsortnames=2,
  uniquename=false,
  uniquelist=false,
  giveninits,
  mincrossrefs=1,
  mergedate=false,
  dashed=false,
  introcite=plain,
  autolang=langname,
]{biblatex}


\DeclareFieldFormat{bbx@introcite}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\introcitepunct}{\mkbibbold{\addcolon\space}}


\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{#1}}

\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareNameAlias{byeditor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{\addspace}

\renewbibmacro*{name:family-given}[4]{%
  \ifuseprefix
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}%
     \ifdefvoid{#3}{}{%
       \ifcapital
         {\mkbibnameprefix{\MakeCapital{#3}}\isdot}
         {\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
       \ifprefchar{}{\bibnamedelimc}}%
     \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot
     \ifboolexpe{%
       test {\ifdefvoid{#2}}
       and
       test {\ifdefvoid{#4}}}
       {}
       {\bibnamedelimd\bibopenparen}%
     \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot}%
     \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{\ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd}\mkbibnamesuffix{#4}\isdot}%
     \ifboolexpe{%
       test {\ifdefvoid{#2}}
       and
       test {\ifdefvoid{#4}}}
       {}
       {\bibcloseparen}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}%
     \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot
     \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamesuffix{#4}\isdot}%
     \ifboolexpe{%
       test {\ifdefvoid{#2}}
       and
       test {\ifdefvoid{#3}}}
       {}
       {\revsdnamepunct\bibopenparen}%
     \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot}%
     \ifdefvoid{#3}{}{\ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd}\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
     \ifboolexpe{%
       test {\ifdefvoid{#2}}
       and
       test {\ifdefvoid{#3}}}
       {}
       {\bibcloseparen}}}

\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{% Based on name:andothers from biblatex.def
  \ifboolexpr{
      test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
      and
      test \ifmorenames
  }
  {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
     {\finalandcomma}
     {}%
   \andothersdelim\bibstring[\emph]{andothers}}
  {}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{origdate}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{cite:labeldate+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
       \printorigdate
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
       \printlabeldateextra}}}

\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{year}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \printorigdate
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
       \printdateextra}}}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\space\textendash\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,unpublished]
  {title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{title}{\mkbibitalic{#1}}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {}
    {\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}


\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}

\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
     \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}
     \clearname{editor}%
     \newunit}%
    \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
    \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}

\renewcommand*{\jourvoldelim}{\addcomma\space}

\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \printfield{issue}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printdate%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \printfield{series}%
       \setunit*{\space}%
       \printfield{number}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\newbibmacro*{institution+location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{institution}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}}


\renewbibmacro*{event+venue+date}{%
  \iffieldundef{eventtitle}
    {}
    {\bibstring{presentedat}%
     \printfield{eventtitle}}%
  \ifboolexpr{
        test {\iffieldundef{venue}}
        and
        test {\iffieldundef{eventyear}}
  }
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addspace}%
     \printfield{venue}%
     \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
     \printeventdate}%
  \newunit
}

%\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,inproceedings,incollection]
%  {pages}{\mkpageprefix[bookpagination]{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{%
    byeditor  = {\iffieldequalstr{keywords}{source}
                   {Établit\space par}%
                   {dir\adddotspace\smartof}},
    in        = {\textit{in}},
    editor    = {dir\adddot},%
    editors   = {dir\adddot},%
    opcit     = {\iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{article}
                   {art\adddotspace cit\adddot}
                   {\mkbibemph{op\adddotspace cit\adddot}}},
    idem      = {\mkbibemph{idem}},%
    byeditor  = {dir\adddot},
    ibidem    = {\emph{ibid\adddot}},%
    mathesis  = {Mém\adddotspace de master\addcomma},
    phdthesis = {Thèse de doct\adddot\space\addcomma},
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@InProceedings{agusta-boularot2017,
  author    = {Agusta-Boularot, Sandrine},
  title     = {Title},
  booktitle = {booktitle},
  year      = {2017},
  crossref  = {agusta-boularot.etal2017},
}
@InProceedings{agusta-boularot2016,
  author    = {Sandrine Agusta-Boularot},
  title     = {Title},
  year      = {2016},
  booktitle = {booktitle},
}
@Book{agusta-boularot.lafon2004,
  title     = {title},
  year      = {2004},
  editor    = {Sandrine Agusta-Boularot and Xavier Lafon},
}
@Book{agusta-boularot.martin2006,
  title     = {title},
  year      = {2006},
  editor    = {Sandrine Agusta-Boularot and Marin Martin},
}
@InProceedings{augustat-boularot.etal2019,
  author    = {Sandrine Agusta-Boularot and Chausserie-Laprée, Jean and Núria Nin},
  title     = {Title},
  booktitle = {booktitle},
  year      = {2019},
  timestamp = {2019-09-11},
}
@Article{agusta-boularot.etal2004,
  author       = {Agusta-Boularot, Sandrine and Christol Martin and Pierre Jack},
  title        = {Title},
  journal      = {Journal},
  year         = {2004},
  volume       = {17},
}
@Article{agusta-boularot.etal2010,
  author       = {Sandrine Agusta-Boularot and Raphaël Golosetti and Delphine Isoardi},
  title        = {Title},
  journal      = {Journal},
  year         = {2010},
  pages        = {109-126},
  volume       = {43},
}
@Book{agusta-boularot.etal2017,
  editor    = {Sandrine Agusta-Boularot and Sandrine Huber and William Van Andringa},
  title     = {Title},
  year      = {2017},
}
@InProceedings{paillet.treziny2004,
  author    = {Paillet, Jean-Louis and Henri Tréziny},
  title     = {Title},
  booktitle = {booktitle},
  year      = {2004},
  editor    = {Agusta-Boularot, Sandrine},
  crossref  = {agusta-boularot.etal2004},
  timestamp = {2019-12-09},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{agusta-boularot2017, agusta-boularot2016, agusta-boularot.lafon2004,
  augustat-boularot.etal2019, agusta-boularot.etal2004,
  agusta-boularot.etal2010, agusta-boularot.etal2017,
  paillet.treziny2004, agusta-boularot.martin2006}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography in desired citation order.]

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried but it doesn't work because my version of texlive was not up to date. It was from 2017 ... I am downloading it but my connection is slow ... very slow

Comment: Thank you very much for sorting and modernizing the code. Everything works well. The authoryear-ext supplement is very practical. I managed to add the changes I wanted. In order to have commas everywhere I added: \ renewcommand * {\ newunitpunct} {\ addcomma \ space}. But is it possible to put an exception for punctuation after the titles of articles and books?

Comment: New problem ... I think I'll have to make a new topic.
When I use "innamebeforetitle= true" the parentheses and the inversion First name / Last name is canceled

Comment: @Axelito The punctuation between author and title can be changed with `\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\space\textendash\space}` (as shown in the example). Please ask a new question about the other issue. Include the code you are using now and an example of how it does not give the expected result.