# How to have the citing order in years (but citing references is according to alphabetical?)

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing, citing

This is another question following [Citing using ; and not &](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/546403/how-to-change-from-citing-a-et-al-2014-2016-b-et-al-2014-to-a-et-al-20/546427?noredirect=1#comment1380526_546427)

How to have the citing order in years (but citing references is according to alphabetical?)

I wish to have:

```
(Hands et al.,2014; 2016; Mudariki et al., 2014)
```

and not (the year 2014 come first)

```
(Hands et al.,2016; 2014; Mudariki et al., 2014)
```

[image]

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}
% \usepackage[style = authoryear-comp, maxnames = 99]{biblatex}

\usepackage[backend=biber, 
% style=authoryear, 
 style=authoryear-comp,
% citestyle=authoryear, 
dashed=false,
maxcitenames=2,
maxbibnames=99,
uniquelist=false, 
giveninits,
alldates=comp, 
dateabbrev=false,
uniquename=false,backref=true,backrefstyle=none]{biblatex}

% \renewcommand*{\compcitedelim}{\addspace\&\space}

% to make volume (number), eg. 4(2)
\newcommand*{\volnumdelim}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\volnumdelim}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\newcommand*{\jourvoldelim}{\addcomma\space}
\newcommand*{\jourserdelim}{\newunitpunct}
\newcommand*{\servoldelim}{\jourvoldelim}
\newcommand*{\volnumdatedelim}{\addspace}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\jourvoldelim}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\jourserdelim}%
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\servoldelim}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\volnumdatedelim}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}  
% to make volume (number), eg. 4(2)
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given} %for second and third author name
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\printtext[bibhyperref]{#1}}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}



\addto\captionsenglish{
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\textsf{List of Figures}}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\textsf{List of Tables}}
}

% Flag for whether to add front matter to TOC
\newtoggle{fulltoc}
\toggletrue{fulltoc}  % Change to \togglefalse{fulltoc} to remove front matter
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}


\usepackage[unicode,colorlinks,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}


% for a chapter edited by a book
\usepackage{xpatch}
% \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space} 
% \renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\space} (to become In:)
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\space} %to delete . after (1997)
% \DeclareFieldFormat[article, incollection, unpublished]{pages}{#1} % to add in PP. (page)
\DeclareFieldFormat[article, incollection, unpublished]{title}{#1}
% \renewcommand{\bibpagespunct}{\ifentrytype{article}{\addcolon}{\addperiod\addspace}} %cancel out this in order to add in PP. (page)


% for title italic
% \DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}} %for title italic in all format (conference, paper..)
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1} %for conference title delete ".."
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}} %for incollecion title italic ONLY
\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}} %for phdthesis title italic ONLY
% for title italic

% to delete "In:" for article
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}
% to delete "In:" for article


% for delete comma after Author A and Aurhor b
\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
   \let\finalandcomma\empty
   \let\finalandsemicolon\empty
 }
\renewcommand{\compcitedelim}{\space\&\space}
\DeclareNameAlias{editorin}{given-family}

\newbibmacro*{byeditor:in}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\printnames[editorin]{editor}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \usebibmacro{editorstrg}%
     \clearname{editor}}}     


\DeclareDelimFormat[textcite]{postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat[parencite]{postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}

% \DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\printtext[bibhyperref]{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}


% for references 's studies (year)
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\newcommand{\mycite}[1]{\citeauthor{#1}'s \citeyear{#1}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthor}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printnames{labelname}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyear} % <======================================
    {}
    {(\bibhyperref{\printdate})}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cbx@textcite}
  {\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{textcite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}  



\makeatletter
\let\abx@macro@textciteOrig\abx@macro@textcite
\renewbibmacro{textcite}{% <============================================
   \bibhyperref{%
   \let\bibhyperref\relax\relax%
   \abx@macro@textciteOrig%
   }%
}%
\makeatother
% for references 's studies (year)





\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{Available at\addcolon\space\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  urlseen = {Accessed},
}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \protected\def\mkdaterangecomp{%
    \mkdaterangetrunc{long}}%
  \protected\def\mkdaterangeterse{%
    \mkdaterangetrunc{short}}%
  \protected\def\mkdaterangecompextra{%
    \mkdaterangetruncextra{long}}%
  \protected\def\mkdaterangeterseextra{%
    \mkdaterangetruncextra{short}}%
  \protected\def\mkbibdatelong#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\thefield{#3}%
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{\nobreakspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}}%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}
      {\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}
      {\dateeraprintpre{#1}\stripzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
}





\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}



@article{hands2014attenuated,
  title={Title 1},
  author={Hands, James R and Dorling, Konrad M and Abel, Peter and Ashton, Katherine M and Brodbelt, Andrew and Davis, Charles and Dawson, Timothy and Jenkinson, Michael D and Lea, Robert W and Walker, Carol and others},
  journal={Journal of biophotonics},
  volume={7},
  number={3-4},
  pages={189--199},
  year={2014},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}

@article{hands2016brain,
  title={Title 2},
  author={Hands, James R and Clemens, Graeme and Stables, Ryan and Ashton, Katherine and Brodbelt, Andrew and Davis, Charles and Dawson, Timothy P and Jenkinson, Michael D and Lea, Robert W and Walker, Carol and others},
  journal={Journal of neuro-oncology},
  volume={127},
  number={3},
  pages={463--472},
  year={2016},
  publisher={Springer}
}

@article{mudariki2014p59diagnostic,
  title={Title 3},
  author={Mudariki, T and Lea, RW and Clemens, G and Baker, MJ},
  journal={Neuro-oncology},
  volume={16},
  number={Suppl 6},
  pages={vi10},
  year={2014},
  publisher={Oxford University Press}
}




\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{WinNT}

The sample ABC is done by \parencite{hands2014attenuated, mudariki2014p59diagnostic, hands2016brain} in a way.



\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that this code example still contains bits of code that I pointed out as problematic in my answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/546403/35864.

Comment: @moewe, yes, I am sorry that later I found out that my uni using Harvard referencing `2016; 2014` is fine.

Comment: Aha. OK. Still the code is problematic as mentioned in my answer. If it gives the right output now, you might as well keep it, since your bibliography/citation code is complex and complicated enough as it is. But keep that in mind if you want to change things later.

Comment: @moewe, thanks for your reply. If I use your previous code, I cannot use `\citeauthor{sigfridsson}'s studies \autocite*{sigfridsson}` where cross referencing in the Author name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following MWE reproduces what you are seeing

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, 
  style=authoryear-comp,
  maxcitenames=2,
  maxbibnames=99,
  uniquelist=false, 
  giveninits,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{hands2014attenuated,
  title    ={Title 1},
  author   ={Hands, James R. and Dorling, Konrad M. and Abel, Peter
             and Ashton, Katherine M. and Brodbelt, Andrew and Davis, Charles
             and Dawson, Timothy and Jenkinson, Michael D. and Lea, Robert W.
             and Walker, Carol and others},
  journal  ={Journal of biophotonics},
  volume   ={7},
  number   ={3-4},
  pages    ={189--199},
  year     ={2014},
}
@article{hands2016brain,
  title   = {Title 2},
  author  = {Hands, James R. and Clemens, Graeme and Stables, Ryan
             and Ashton, Katherine and Brodbelt, Andrew and Davis, Charles
             and Dawson, Timothy P. and Jenkinson, Michael D.
             and Lea, Robert W. and Walker, Carol and others},
  journal = {Journal of neuro-oncology},
  volume  = {127},
  number  = {3},
  pages   = {463--472},
  year    = {2016},
}
@article{mudariki2014p59diagnostic,
  title   = {Title 3},
  author  = {Mudariki, T. and Lea, R. W.  and Clemens, G. and Baker, M. J.},
  journal = {Neuro-oncology},
  volume  = {16},
  number  = {Suppl 6},
  pages   = {vi10},
  year    = {2014},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem
\parencite{hands2014attenuated, mudariki2014p59diagnostic, hands2016brain}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The problem occurs because citations are sorted exactly like the bibliography. If you look closely at the bibliography you'll see that `hands2016brain` sorts before `hands2014attenuated` because sorting takes into account all shown co-authors (and Clemens from the 2016 paper sorts before Dorling of the 2014 paper).

I don't think there is a good solution here, but you can add `maxsortnames=2,` to your bibliography options (note that the option *must* be set *after* `maxbibnames`/`maxnames` if a `maxbibnames`/`maxnames` is present; see also [Sorting issue with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/544285/35864), [How to establish a complex sorting scheme of references in biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83738/35864)). That way sorting will only consider the same number of names that are shown in citations, so your citations will appear sorted correctly. The bibliography will be a bit out of order, though.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, 
  style=authoryear-comp,
  maxcitenames=2,
  maxbibnames=99,
  maxsortnames=2,
  uniquelist=false, 
  giveninits,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{hands2014attenuated,
  title    ={Title 1},
  author   ={Hands, James R. and Dorling, Konrad M. and Abel, Peter
             and Ashton, Katherine M. and Brodbelt, Andrew and Davis, Charles
             and Dawson, Timothy and Jenkinson, Michael D. and Lea, Robert W.
             and Walker, Carol and others},
  journal  ={Journal of biophotonics},
  volume   ={7},
  number   ={3-4},
  pages    ={189--199},
  year     ={2014},
}
@article{hands2016brain,
  title   = {Title 2},
  author  = {Hands, James R. and Clemens, Graeme and Stables, Ryan
             and Ashton, Katherine and Brodbelt, Andrew and Davis, Charles
             and Dawson, Timothy P. and Jenkinson, Michael D.
             and Lea, Robert W. and Walker, Carol and others},
  journal = {Journal of neuro-oncology},
  volume  = {127},
  number  = {3},
  pages   = {463--472},
  year    = {2016},
}
@article{mudariki2014p59diagnostic,
  title   = {Title 3},
  author  = {Mudariki, T. and Lea, R. W.  and Clemens, G. and Baker, M. J.},
  journal = {Neuro-oncology},
  volume  = {16},
  number  = {Suppl 6},
  pages   = {vi10},
  year    = {2014},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem
\parencite{hands2014attenuated, mudariki2014p59diagnostic, hands2016brain}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Hands 2014 > Hands 2016]

Comment: thanks. `maxsortnames=2` works. Thanks for your time.